# How to use NLog in linux with mono?

Tags: c#, mono, debian, nlog

I'm porting a C# application which is completely written in windows under Visual studio which did all the nice bits for me. Now I'm finding it difficult to be able to run it under Linux with mono. I'm using a few libraries in it which I included but I'm unable to use NLog which I dont find any native version for debian-squeeze. **How should I link Nlog into my project and also the config file for it?**

p.s : I'm compiling under debian-squeeze x64.

Comment: I just compiled the NLog assembly from source in the debian and used it. And more on info, there is NLog mono assembly available for download also. On cases, it complained about the 64-bit incompatibility and I was content to compile it for my own which happened without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://nlog-project.org/2011/10/30/using-nlog-with-mono.html).
There is a problem with the latest NLog release - check if you can use NLog 1.0.
In general this [article](http://www.mono-project.com/Assemblies_and_the_GAC) explains how you could install the NLog assembly for your program when you copy the compiled dll from your Windows machince to your Debian box.

Comment: That issue is not going to be my concern as of now. But I will see how the article helps in bringing the assembly to debian and how it links up.